# DateTime comparison in ObjectQuery.Where

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, datetime, nullable, query-builder

I'm using Entity Framework, and I have a COMMENT entity.  A COMMENT has a DATEMODIFIED property, which is a Nullable Date. I'm trying to build a query that will filter COMMENTs by date, so I create a startDate object, and do the following:

```
Dim q As ObjectQuery(Of COMMENT) = _ 
   (From c In model.COMMENT Select c)

If startDate.HasValue Then
   q = q.Where(Function(c) startDate.Value <= c.DATEMODIFIED)
End If
```

The problem is that q.toList() is not returning any comments, even though I think it should. All comments in the database have DATEMODIFIED values, and even if I pass in DateTime.MinValue as the startDate, the query still doesn't match any entities.

I set a breakpoint before the If-Statement and used the Visual Studio Watch Window to try and see what's going on:

```
q.ToList()(0).DATEMODIFIED    'Returns the expected date 
startDate.Value               'Returns the expected date 
startDate.Value <= q.ToList()(0).DATEMODIFIED    'Returns True...
```

But once once it hits the  q = q.Where(predicate) part, q.ToList() no longer returns any entries.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Look at the ObjectQuery.ToTraceString() (or SQL Profiler) and post it here, with param values.

Comment: SELECT 
1 AS C1, 
"Extent1".COMMENT_ID AS COMMENT_ID, 
"Extent1".COMMENTS AS COMMENTS, 
"Extent1".SYS_GEN_FLAG AS SYS_GEN_FLAG, 
"Extent1".ITEM_ID AS ITEM_ID, 
"Extent1".MODIFIEDBY AS MODIFIEDBY, 
"Extent1".DATEMODIFIED AS DATEMODIFIED, 
"Extent1".COMPANY_ID AS COMPANY_ID, 
"Extent1".ORG_ID AS ORG_ID, 
"Extent1".SUBTAB_ID AS SUBTAB_ID, 
"Extent1".USER_ID AS USER_ID, 
"Extent1".COMPANY_SECTION AS COMPANY_SECTION
FROM AIP.CO_COMMENT "Extent1"
WHERE ("Extent1".COMPANY_ID = :p__linq__49) AND ("Extent1".DATEMODIFIED >= ( CAST(:p__linq__53 AS TIMESTAMP(9))))

Comment: Very helpful. Can you post the value of objectQuery.Parameters("p__linq__53")  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Oops, I forgot that, with LINQ to Entities, all WHERE expressions are translated into SQL calls instead of being post-processed in code-- so the debugging suggestions below won't necessarily work.

Therefore, I'd start by running the same generated SQL statement against your database, and validating whether the SQL generated by your Entity Framework provider is actually returning the data you expect.  @Craig Stuntz's comment above is definitely on the right track here to help you do this.  Once you have the parameterized SQL, I'd try executing that SQL directly from your code (using `System.Data.OracleClient`) and validating that you actually get results back from that query.  Remember to inject the same parameter values that you get from `ObjectQuery.Parameters`.  Alternatively, you could stick the parameters in yourself and execute the query from your Oracle client app of choice.

If you don't get results from that SQL, then it's possible that devArt's provider is building the query incorrectly.

**you can ignore what's below here, since it applies to troubleshooting LINQ-to-Objects but not LINQ-to-Entities**

Some ideas to diagnose this:

first, try this in your watch window:

```
q.Where(Function(c) startDate.Value <= c.DATEMODIFIED).Count()
```

I'm assuming this will return zero, but it's worth eliminating as many other variables to make sure you're really not getting any results.

Next, I'd try is to define your LINQ query a bit differently-- instead of appending the Where() separately, try using two queries, like this:

```
Dim q As ObjectQuery(Of COMMENT)
If startDate.HasValue Then
    q = (From c In model.COMMENT Where startDate.Value <= c.DATEMODIFIED Select c)
Else
    q = (From c In model.COMMENT Select c)
End If
```

If this works, then there's something wrong with how the Where clause is being attached to your existing LINQ query-- perhaps a bug in your DBMS's entity-framework provider?

If that still doesn't work, the next step I'd take to diagnose would be to verify that the code inside the where clause is being called, and checking the values passed into that code.  I couldn't figure out how to set intra-line breakpoints in VB like one can do in C#, but you can easily (temporarily) refactor your lambda into a separate function and set the breakpoint there. Like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim testDate As Date = New Date(2005, 1, 1)
    Dim x = New List(Of Date?)
    x.Add(New Date(2009, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2008, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2007, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2006, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2005, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2004, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2003, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2002, 1, 1))
    x.Add(New Date(2001, 1, 1))
    Dim y = From n In x Select n
    y = y.Where(Function(val) test(val, testDate))
    Dim z = y.ToArray()
End Sub

Function test(ByVal date1 As Date, ByVal date2 As Date) As Boolean
    test = date1 >= date2
End Function
```

Check the values being sent into your comparison function-- are they valid? Does the comparison return what you expect it to?

Comment: Justin, thanks for your reply.  When I tried your first suggestion, it said "Evaluation of lambda expressions is not valid in the debugger".  However q.tolist().Count()   does indeed return 0.

For your second suggestion, rearranging the query made no difference.

Finally, defining the "test()" function and substituting it for the <= comparison caused Entity Framework to throw an exception (slightly paraphrased here):

System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Test' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: DBMS is Oracle 10g, and EF provider is DevArt dotConnect for oracle.