# Comparing DateTime values in EntitySQL when starting with a querystring

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, query-builder, entity-sql

I am using the `QueryBuilder` as following:

```
var queryString = String.Format(
    "SELECT VALUE e FROM Entity AS e WHERE e.EndDate {0} {1} ",
    operator,
    DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
);
ObjectQuery<Entity> query = new ObjectQuery<Entity>(queryString, Context);
```

Please note that I extremely simplified this example and that my goal is to build the query as string before creating a `QueryBuilder` instance. (As long as this is possible)

I already tried the following

```
...DateTime.Today.AddYears(1)...
...DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).ToString()...
...DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).ToString("yyy\MM\dd")...
```

which all result in a exception which says that I either cannot compare DateTime with a String or with a Int32.

I'm beginning to asking me if this is possible at all with this approach...

Comment: Any reason you really want to have the whole thing as a string, instead of building it as an `ObjectQuery` with parameters?

Comment: According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399176.aspx) you need to pass it as `DATETIME'2006-10-1 23:11'`

Comment: @Jon Skeet No really. The only one is that all queries are written this way and that I need to refactor each completly cause that peace of code is somewhere in the middle and just a small part of a greater WHERE... If so I can do it like `query.Where("entity.EndDate > @dateparam", new ObjectParameter("dateparam", DateTime.Today));` ??

Comment: I believe you have your answer at below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671254/datetime-comparison-in-objectquery-where

Comment: @Ravia that Stackoverflow question you are referring isn't really helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Entity SQL [DateTime literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399176.aspx) must be expressed in the following format:

```
DATETIME'2012-02-02 16:26'
```

where both the date and time parts are mandatory. For example:

```
"SELECT VALUE e FROM Entity AS e WHERE e.EndDate > DATETIME'2012-02-02 16:26'"
```

Comment: Thank u...working fine... but i have one more question. i am search record with date and  time but i want to ignore millisecond of time then how to achieve this?

Comment: @PatelRikin In the example above milliseconds are already ignored since they're not part of the selection clause. What's your scenario?

Comment: if date save in db like 2012-02-02 16:26.321 and run above query then this record not fetch. and it only fetch up 2012-02-02 16:25